# Is is recommended to use JSON Schema Validation in the place of Bean Validation JSR303 for Spring Boot Rest APIs?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, bean-validation

Can we use JSON Schema Validation in the place of Java Bean Validation JSR303 for Spring Boot Rest APIs for Enterprise Applications? Which one is more efficient to validate request Payload to Spring Boot Rest APIs?

(i.e. performance wise, cross-validation wise and RegEx pattern based validation)

Answer (score 3):

It is a good question and there are no definitive answers for it as, perhaps, it is dependent on the application domain and remains subjective to that. At the base level (which usually covers 90%) of all use cases of validating user input to the REST service, both have the equivalent facility to validate data adequately. Both support constraints which can be used to achieve the same result.

However, on one front Bean Validation stands out is its ability to define custom validators, which can be used to validate very specific domain/application dependent constraints. For example, if there is case where a class which has 3 attributes (say, A,B and C) and a constraint is required that is either A occurs or B & C occurs but not both, then it is not really possible to put a constraint in JSON schema directly, it has to be handled through design of the schema (similarly in XML, actually it is more complicated with XML).

On the other hand in Bean Validation a custom validator can be written to handle this situation quite easily.

However, these kind of cases are few and far between.

Another point to consider is the integration of the Bean Validation in the underlying framework e.g. Spring, Jersey, RESTEasy etc., JSON schema validation is not yet integrated in the frameworks.

Therefore, given the support for the tech, it is perhaps better to stick with Bean Validation 2.0 and leverage the underlying frameworks capability to validation (this is, however, purely my view).

Comment: The case you mentioned (either A or B & C but not both) can be defined with `oneOf` keyword if OpenAPI schema is chosen as JSON valiadtion schema.

Answer (score 0):

From an application development prospect, Java bean validator is sufficient for the business needs. From a system integration point, JSON schema externalizes the business rules and provides a platform independent interface control. So if your system involves many subsystems, JSON schema gives a better way to verify message payload.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer OpenAPI Specification, which can be regarded roughly as a JSON Schema dialect, to bean validation 2.0 (JSR380).

- OpenAPI is the de-facto (correct me) standard to describe RESTful API today. There are tools for validation accroding to OpenAPI spec is available, an incomplete collection can be found at [here](https://openapi.tools/). And of course it works well with Java/Spring.
- OpenAPI validates JSON string rather than a POJO, thus it can handle the following case naturally while bean validation in Java cannot: say i want to validate the object in the request body of a PATCH request, and the object must have a property named A, while the value of A is can be null;
- And there are more than validation you can do with an OpenAPI spec in your hand. Because an OpenAPI schema does not only define what the data model of RESTful API looks like, it also describes other aspects (endponts, parameters and status code etc.) of the API in the same file. Out there are a bunch of [code generators](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators) to auto-generate server-side or client-side code to serve requests or retrive response in whatever language.